# Open VS code from terminal in devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I can run `code /path/to/folder` in the terminal to have VS code open the given folder.

Now suppose I have a devcontainer setup, in the folder `/path/to/folder/.devcontainer`. Is there a flag or something I can pass in the command `code /path/to/folder` to instruct VS code to open the workspace in the container?